# Material drop down error proptypes to prop.types

Tags: react-native

Could you please help me with this.

I installed a module named "react-native-material-dropdown". It threw the following error:

" undefined is not an object (evauating _reactNative.Animated.Text.PropTypes.style) ". 
The above error came from react-native-material-textfield module.

I researched and found the following command should be used: 
But still, the problem persisted for react-native-material-textfield module.
Could you please suggest how to resolve the module error highlighted above. I am not an expert in react native.

`npx react-codemod React-PropTypes-to-prop-types C:\invent\node_modules\react-native-material-textfield --force`

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see [on this discussion](https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-dropdown/issues/220), it's an issue is with 'react-native' 0.62.2 version that removed **propTypes** from core components. You can do [what they explained here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28418#issuecomment-617582579):

```
npm i https://github.com/noway/react-native-material-dropdown
```